# IOStream.flush timed out: What does it mean?

Tags: python, macos, spyder, flush

I get the following message in my console while I am running some code.

The code is still running so I am not sure if this is an error or not.

After a while the code stop to run and it seems that I get the output as I want it but now is difficult for me to understand if it gave any issues or not.

Any idea?

I understand it has something to do with memory but I cannot find a definition of it.

```
In [4]: daily_transactions, transactions = strategy_transactions(price = price_data, 
                                                         timeframe = 'W-SUN',
                                                         f_strategy = MACD_XOVER)

Output from spyder call 'get_namespace_view':
IOStream.flush timed out
IOStream.flush timed out
IOStream.flush timed out
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*). I don't know where that message comes from, but we can avoid showing it. I'll try to include a fix for it in our next version (5.2.2), to be released next week.

Answer (score 2):

hi this Error is from ***IPython***

From the [IPython kernel options](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/4.x/config/options/kernel.html)

> Set the size of the output cache. The default is 1000, you can change it permanently in your config file. Setting it to 0 completely disables the caching system, and the minimum value accepted is 20 *(if you provide a value less than 20, it is reset to 0 and a warning is issued). This limit is defined because otherwise you’ll spend more time re-flushing a too small cache than working

or, from a [comment on a iPython kernel issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/334#issuecomment-1117231330), by [daniel-fry](https://github.com/daniel-fry):

> I put a 1 second sleep in the iterations that solved it

nice job

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the problem is but I managed to go around it by saving the important data beforehand and reseting kernel in a loop.

Basically, every after any N number of iterations in a loop, I save the important and relevant data, reset the kernel, import the required libraries and then load the relevant data.

I understand that this is not an optimal way of solving the problem, but I did the trick for me.

The reset code on python through jupyter notebook is:

```
%reset -f
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR:

Try limiting your output to console as much as possible while working with threads/tasks and especially **waiting** on them. This also means limiting `tqdm` usage/updates.

### Long answer:

In my particular case the problem was seemingly caused by `tqdm` together with `ThreadPoolExecutor`. I manually update `tqdm` counter multiple times (hunderds of thousands) from multiple threads which supposedly got some `iPython` buffers overloaded without opportunity to flush.

Without knowing any details about `iPython` internals my assumptions would be that

1. `tqdm` spams quite a lot (every `.update()`) into output console and
2. while (I guess) normally `iPython` buffers get flushed out in between code execution - in my case that was prevented by `concurrent.futures.wait(tasks)` thus overloading the buffer and getting stuck in a weird deadlock when (a) console output buffer would be filled out, "pause" execution of my own tasks waiting for flush, and in turn `.wait(tasks)` would prevent buffer from flushing out.

I could've tried [changing default iPython cache size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74846739), which I think is still a valid option in some cases, but I ended up just changing my code so that it would update `tqdm` counter every batch instead of every single time.

This is not an ideal solution since, if I'm correct, it would still get buffers filled out, just on much larger data, but it suffices for now. "Proper" solution would be to somehow periodically yield control back to `iPython` worker thread or something which would flush buffer mid-`.wait(tasks)`, but that would be drastically more difficult to implement.